# Create a unique pointer from raw pointer ensuring that it will be deleted when out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11

We are using boost Circular queue (specifically a `boost::circular_buffer<std::unique_ptr<Interface>>`) in our code. I am to write a code that will get a specific type of data from queue else delete from queue if not.

```
void chkdata()
{
.....
 // auto data = get the first element from the circular buffer
// need to implement like this so that auto delete will happen
}
```

How can I implement the same?

Comment: Isn't it just `auto rawpacket = std::move(buf.front())`?

Comment: What type is in `buffer`?

Comment: Can you please improve your question? I find it really hard to understand what exactly it is that you want to achieve.

Comment: buf is a circular queue where different types of messages type will be written by casting it to a generic type

Comment: Is the goal to make `std::make_unique<decltype(buffer.front().release())>(buffer.front().release());` less of a mouthful?  I'm failing to understand what the issue is here.

Comment: @Programmer just show `buffer` type declaration, I do not understand your interpretation.

Comment: When I read buf circular array I get different type of message buffer - since at other end I am reading it I need to make sure that the read buffer are deleted. Since data in buffer is written like - Obj* data; buf.insert(data);

Comment: boost::circular_buffer<std::unique_ptr<IMsg>> - where IMsg is an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `rawpacket` to destroy the message when it leaves scope, you just need

```
auto rawpacket = std::move(buf.front());
```

It also sounds like you should remove the (now null) moved-from pointer from the queue

```
buf.pop_front();
```

You are being confused by the implicit conversion occuring at the insertion side, where a `std::unique_ptr<IMsg>` is constructed from a `Obj*` in the call `buf.insert(data);`. Presumably `Obj` inherits from `IMsg`.

Comment: I would clarify that this move-constructs a fresh unique_ptr, but yes this is the right approach